# $PATH is different for startup programs

Tags: bash, startup, environment-variables, bashrc

I have a .sh file with `echo $PATH`. When opening a terminal, the PATH is how it is supposed to be, it includes all the additions in `.bashrc`.

I open the startup menu and set this script to run on startup. But when it runs, the $PATH variable only has `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`.
It should be much longer.

Things I've tried putting before the `echo`:

- `source ~/.bashrc`
- `. ~/.bashrc`
- `source ~/.profile`
- `exec bash`

Things I've tried for running the command itself:

- `konsole -e ...`
- `bash -c ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to the `PATH` defined in `~/.bashrc` will only be in effect in an interactive shell, i.e., every time you open a terminal. To have changes to a `PATH` take effect anytime you login to the desktop, include these changes in `~/.profile` instead. That file is read for a login shell, thus after you log in to the system.

Comment: I commented out the interactive shell check in .bashrc and that fixed it. But are there any problems I should be aware of with doing this?